# weak convergence, convex hull and strong convergence.

Tags: functional-analysis, weak-convergence

Denote $K_n:= $the convex hull of $\cup_{i=1}^n\{x_i\}$. Let $E$ be a Banach space and let $(x_n)$ be a sequence in $E$ such that $x_n \to x$ weakly. Show that there exists a sequence $(z_n)$ in $E$ such that $z_n$ in $K_n$ for any $n \in \mathbb N$, and $z_n \to x$ strongly.

The usual trick for this kind of problem is to consider convex neighborhoods of $X$, say balls, but it seems not to work here.

Comment: This result is known as Mazur's Lemma.